# Erro na compilação de um arquivo .cpp usando MinGW

Tags: c++, compiladores, mingw

Hoje eu reinstalei o MinGW e fiz o setup dele novamente, testei várias vezes com alguns programas em c++ e estava dando tudo certo, mas agora eu tento criar novos programas e quando vou compilar usando o comando:

```
g++ -o file file.cpp
```

Ele acusa o seguinte erro:

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`

Eu consegui resolver o problema trocando a declaração da main de:

```
int main()
```

para:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

E agora consigo compilar normalmente os programas. No entanto, eu gostaria de saber qual foi a origem do erro, já que hoje mais cedo eu escrevi e compilei programas com a estrutura da main do exemplo de cima sem nenhum problema. Alguém saberia me dizer?

Comment: Qual foi o código que tentou compilar e deu erro?

Comment: Não terá tentado compilar antes sequer de gravar o arquivo ?

Answer (score 0):

Se você está utilizando o CodeBlocks no windows, é bom reinstalar [codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) pois assim provavelmente corrige este problema.